# node https for local development

Tags: node.js, https

I need an https server for local development of my web app. For the frontend part of my app Webpack does that easily using only `--https` flag. And it was very surprising to me to find out there is no easy way to do this for the node backend. Turned out I have to manually generate certificates, store them and pass them to the https server constructor. And I couldn't find any lib that handles this under the hood. I can't be the first person who faces this issue.

Third party proxy server is not an option in my case. Everything has to be able to work locally.